# Access array value from function

Tags: javascript, html

I simply want to access the value of array status from another function. However, the alert is giving me value as undefined. Here's my code:

**Test.php:**

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var status=[];
            status[0]='1';

            calculateInput();

            function calculateInput(){
                alert(status[0]);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are you calling `calculateInput()`

Comment: Maybe clarify type="text/javascript" in the script-tag? Not sure that that's the problem...

Comment: I even tried to remove var initilization for status as i had read somewhere to make array global you have to use status=[]; but still value comes as undefined

Comment: Interestingly, your code works just fine in a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/A7Z3N/ (Firefox, at least.)

Comment: In the javascript itself there is function call for calculateInput

Comment: I opened the jsfiddle link and i got undefined. Btw im using chrome

Comment: Okay, makes sense. I'm using Firefox, guess they have different ways of handling the name `status`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are colliding with `window.status`:

```js
function calculateInput () {
    alert( status === window.status ); // true
}
```

To avoid this, rename your array or get out of the global scope:

```js
(function IIFE () {

    var status = [];

    status[0] = "1";

    calculateInput();

    function calculateInput () {
        alert( status[0] );
    }

}());
```

Comment: actually I also want to use the array in another function. So I have to use global.

Comment: @DikshayPoojary You don't need to put it in the global scope. If you still want to, namespace it or given it a different name.

Comment: JavaScript is great, you can overwrite `undefined` "constant", but `window.status` is protected... :)

Answer (score 1):

Change your variable name from status to something else

ex.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <script>
            var mystatus=[];
            mystatus[0]='1';

            calculateInput();

            function calculateInput(){
                alert(mystatus[0]);
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```